# Spyder Debugger Crashes

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Mac OS 12.2.1
Anaconda Navigator 2.1.2
Spyder 5.1.5

I’ve been to the Spyder Web site, performed what was described as “Basic First-Aid” as well as “Emergency CPR” without satisfactory resolution.  The first symptom was that the debugger just hung.  After performing the suggested fixes (updating Anaconda, Spyder, and Spyder dependencies, system re-boot, etc.), the debugger now reports: “OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database.”

I’m at my wits’ end.  I’m wondering if I need to completely re-install all of Anaconda.  Is there a “best way” to do this?  Is there a web site that I can consult that will demonstrate how to get a fresh installation?

ADDENDUM

So, I cleaned Anaconda from my machine (what a horrific experience!) and re-installed it, using conda for both tasks.  I started Anaconda and then launched Spyder.  Then I loaded one of my modules, set a brake-point in the editor, and boom! The Spyder debugger worked.  However, the new installation of Anaconda was lacking a particular library: pyreadstat.  I used conda to get this library.  I then launched Anaconda again, saw that pyreadstat was now in the base(root) environment.  I ran one of my packages (8 modules mainly consisting of numpy and itertools manipulations of N-D arrays) and everything worked, including calls to pyreadstat to read SAS datasets.  Okay, everything seemed copacetic.  So, I tried to debug one of my modules and the debugger failed again, returning the message: “OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database.”  WTF!  Is conda trashing Spyder’s debugger in some mysterious way?  I don’t get it.  Why would pyreadstat affect Spyder.  It must be conda.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, in the Mac Terminal app, I typed:

--> conda install -c conda-forge spyder=5.2.2

Boom! All is well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows10 with spyder version 5.1.5.
For me, updating Spyder to the newest version as suggested [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16444) worked as well. This can be done in two ways:

## Console

Open the console or, if you're working on Windows, the [Anaconda Prompt](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/) and type the following commands in order to first uninstall spyder, and then re-install the newest version (just updating didn't work for me).

```
conda remove -n myenv spyder
conda install -n myenv -c conda-forge spyder
```

- The first command, [remove](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html), uninstalls spyder in the virtualenv called 'myenv'. If you don't use virtualenvs, just leave the `-n myenv` aside.
- The second command, [install](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html) installs spyder from the third-party channel `conda-forge` instead of the official channel `defaults`. This option is necessary in order to install a spyder version newer than 5.1.5

## Anaconda Navigator

- Uninstall Spyder: In the "Home" tab, select the correct virtual environment in the "Applications on" dropdown menu. Then click on the gear symbol in the upper right corner of the spyder tile and select "remove application".
- Add `conda-forge` to your environment's channels: This is nicely described at the bottom of [this](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html) page.
- Install spyder again, in the way you did it the first time.
- Click again on the gear on the spyder tile, choose "install specific version" in order to update to the newest version. Now, versions newer than 5.1.5 should be available.